# Looking for the itcvd vehicle detection dataset

Tags: data-request, aerial-photography

In the article [Vehicle Detection in Aerial Images](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.07339.pdf) the authors used a dataset of vehicles from aerial view called *itcvd*. I could not find any information on it online.

How can I obtain more information on it or download it?

Answer (score 1):

Halfway they state:

> Furthermore, we introduce a novel large-scale
>   and well annotated dataset for quantitative vehicle detection evaluation - ITCVD.
>   Towards this goal, we collected 173 images with 29088 vehicles, where each vehicle in the ITCVD dataset is manually annotated using a bounding box.

I think they used this one as the source:

The last-but-one reference in the paper gives you your clue: *Xia, G., Bai, X., Ding, J., Zhu, Z., Belongie, S., Luo, J., Datcu, M., Pelillo, M.,
Zhang, L., 2017. DOTA: A large-scale dataset for object detection in aerial images. CoRR abs/1711.10398.*

If you use *DOTA: A large-scale dataset for object detection in aerial images* as search term you find it [here](https://captain-whu.github.io/DOTA/).

Alternatively, contact the authors. They say:

> We make our code and dataset online
>   available

Answer (score 0):

I found a link on the author's website: https://sites.google.com/site/michaelyingyang/publica

Dataset: https://eostore.itc.utwente.nl:5001/fsdownload/zZYfgbB2X/ITCVD

The SSL certificate was invalid but I proceed anyhow and could download the data. I swear to God, this is not a scam. The data is really there.

Comment: Saying "I swear to God this is not a scam" makes this sound 100% more like a scam.